# Best way to notify a channel about model (context) changes in phoenix 1.3?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to notify a channel about create/update/delete events on my model.

For example:

```
defmodule PhoenixLibrary.Books do
  def delete_book(%Book{} = book) do
    PhoenixLibrary.Endpoint.broadcast("books:updates", "delete", %{id: book.id})
    Repo.delete(book)
  end
end
```

Is it ok to put store such code in context?

I read somewhere that "elixir way" it to put such code into controller. But I would like to broadcast those events when context is changed from console or from admin panel (like ex_admin).

Comment: As for me, your code has a bad smell. It has two side effects. It is not a big problem if it is your _focade_ module and if it is well tested. But for services(or other stuff) better to keep single responsibility principle.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to Phoenix but that looks good to me. Some might argue whether the broadcast belongs to your business logic or not but doing it in the context as in your example is the simplest and most consistent way without overcomplicating.